# Trying to insert value of checkbox into mysql database in android

Tags: java, php, android

i am kavin. i am creating a check list... In that i am trying to verify a list using checkbox...after that but clicking a button my checkbox value should inserted in the mysql database... But i tried most of Technics, i cannot get the value. i just want to get the value of the checkbox and wanted to inserted in the mysql databse.. anyone help me ... i am a beginner to android and java so explain me in a easy way...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
CheckBox box;
Button btn_test;


private static final String REGISTER_URL="http://192.168.0.106/test/checkin.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);


    box = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    btn_test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn_test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerUser();
        }
    });
}

private void registerUser() {
   // box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    //public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
      //  if(isChecked){
        //    String date = box.toString().trim().toLowerCase();
          //  register(date); } } }  );
    Boolean box1 = ((CheckBox)box).isChecked();
    if (box1) {
        String date = "yes";
    } else {
        String date = "No";
    }
    String date = box1.toString();
    register(date);
}

private void register(String date){
    String urlSuffix = "?date=" + date;
    class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait", null, true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String s = params[0];
            BufferedReader bufferReader=null;
            try {
                URL url=new URL(REGISTER_URL+s);
                HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                bufferReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String result;
                result=bufferReader.readLine();
                return  result;

            }catch (Exception e){
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
    RegisterUser ur=new RegisterUser();
    ur.execute(urlSuffix);
}
}
```

My php program,

```
<?php
require "conn.php";

$date = $_GET['date'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO check (date) VALUES('$date')";

    if($conn->query($sql)){

        echo 'successfully registered';

}
    else{

        echo 'oops! Please try again!';

    }


        $conn->close();

    }           
    ?>
```

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: Sorry, but for that itself i had not received any answer.. so only i posted it once again in a full view...